# laravel 4.2 error for datetime

Tags: php, laravel

We have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="insert">
    <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="llogarit()"> Llogarit </button>
</form>
```

this model:

```
<?php

namespace Mejili\Core\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Timer extends Eloquent{

 protected $table = 'timer';

    protected $fillable = ['count_id', 'ora'];

}
```

and this function

```
public function insert()
{
    $time = Input::get('datetime');
    $timer = new Timer;
    $timer->ora = $time;
    $timer->save();
}
```

Laravel gives us this error:

**Class 'Mejili\Core\Models\Timer' not found**

where do we have the error! Any help would be welcomed :)

Comment: what does `composer dumpautoload` returning from console?

Comment: what's with `::ublic function insert()`?

Comment: @madalinivascu just edited was my mistake its `public function insert()`

Comment: @Chay22 **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `timer` (`ora`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-01-01T01:01, 2017-11-24 11:30:10, 2017-11-24 11:30:10))**  this is what i get

Comment: you don't have a `updated_at` column in your db

Comment: @Chay22 thank you way to much :D. Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem properly. i think your Timer model is missing and you need to create the Timer Model with this command:-

```
select your directory -> php artisan make:model Timer
```

And after that you need to use that Modelin your controller like this way :-

```
use App\Timer; // add before controller
public function insert()
{
   $time = Input::get('datetime');
   $timer = new Timer;
   $timer->ora = $time;
   $timer->save();
}
```

Hope it helps!